# WSO2 API Manager NFS for Active-Active Deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, nfs

I am trying to setup Active-Active setup for the WSO2 API Manager by following this url:[Configuring an Active-Active Deployment](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment)

Everything is working fine except step 5 where I am trying to setup NFS. I moved /repository/deployment/server folder to another drive. For e.g. at location:

```
D:/WSO2AM/Deployment/server
```

so that both nodes can share deployment folder together.

Now not knowing what config files to change to point deployment folder to location other than default, I made changes to carbon.xml and made changes to an element "`RepositoryLocation`" and set it to `D:/WSO2AM/Deployment/server` but uit looks like it is not enough. When I start the server, I get the following error messsage:

```
FATAL - SynapseControllerFactory The synapse.xml location .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default doesn't exist
[2019-03-12 15:54:49,332] FATAL - ServiceBusInitializer Couldn't initialize the ESB...
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location .\.\repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default doesn't exist
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me setup NFS so that both nodes can share same deployment folder and I don't have to worry about syncing them through some other mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for almost a day, I found a solution in WSO2's completely separate thread.
[Enable Artifact Synchronization](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+2#SettingUpDeploymentPattern2-Enablingartifactsynchronization)

In this thread, they are asking to create a SMB share (for Windows) for Deployment and tenants directory, for APIM purpose, we need to create SMB share for the directory /repositiry/deployment/server directory.

It is just one command away to create a symbolic link as seen below:

```
mklink /D <APIM_HOME>/repositiry/deployment/server D:\WSO2\Shared\deployment\server
```

We need to create symlink in both nodes to point to the same location.

Once done, no configuration changes needed on APIM side. It will work by default and you have following scenario configured.

[image: NFS Configuration for Active-Active configuration]